# Merge of multiple values into one key on the same dictionary in Python

Tags: python

My input dataset is like this -

```
Name : 'Thomas P Williams' 
address : '' 
Street : '4030 Polk Street' 
Pincode : '95926' 
Country : 'US'
```

I read above-mentioned input file in the code and splitting it using delimiter as **":"** and mapping the dictionary key value pair like this -

```
record[columns[0].strip()] = columns[1].strip()
```

The dictionary is declared as :

```
record = dict.fromkeys([ "Name" ,"address" ,"street" ,"Pincode","country"])

cols = [record["Name"] ,record["address"] ,record["street"] ,record["Pincode"] , record["country"] ]
```

The Desired output that i want in my final file is : to make address out of using **street, Pincode and country** values like following:

```
{'Name': Thomas P Williams, 
'address': '4030 Polk Street, 95926, US'}
```

Here I have generated ***address*** **from 3 keys i.e. *street, Pincode and country*.**

Please suggest what would be the right way to do this.

Comment: Show the original dictionary and your desired output dictionary

Comment: @Chris_Rands Added my desire output in question itself hope this will make you understand my question more.

Comment: "If I have the name, street....". Where do you have this information? In which variable and which format?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I am reading one file in the same format I mentioned above, but consolidation need to be done to get the address from different  values and at the end, I will going to write this into CSV file using - csv.writer(mycsvfile,delimiter='~').writerow(cols)

Comment: You should put in your question an example of all variables involved in your problem. Otherwise nobody will be able to help

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki thanks for your words :) let me change the question a little

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare a new `dict`
2. Assign `columns[0].strip()` to the `dict`
   e.g `myDict['Name'] = columns[0].strip()`
3. Assign columns 2,3,4 to `myDict['address']`